# Taking text file input as list of class item elements

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class `threeItems` defined as

```
class threeItems:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c=0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I want to feed input from a text file as a series of `threeItems` objects, each instance object separated by a space character and each `threeItems` object to be separated by a newline character. For example,

```
0 3 2
4 5 8
```

becomes a `threeItems` list of length `n=2` called `out` with `out[0].a = 0`, `out[0].b = 3`, `out[0].c = 2`, and `out[1].a = 4`, `out[1].b = 5`, and `out[1].c = 8`. I think it should be something like

```
x, y, z = [int(x) for x in input().split()] for _ in range(n)]
```

but I'm not sure how to then append these triples as elements to `out`. I am still somewhat of a novice at Python, so this may be obvious, but I can't find any answers to this elsewhere.

Comment: Could you give the definition of `threeItems`?

Comment: Edited to contain `threeItems` definition

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.append()` along with a call to the `threeItems` constructor:

```py
result = []
with open('in.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        x, y, z = [int(item) for item in line.rstrip().split()]
        result.append(threeItems(x, y, z))

for item in result:
    print(item.a, item.b, item.c)
```

This outputs:

```py
0 3 2
4 5 8
```

Comment: Thank you--how would you alter this if you don't know the filename already and we were just piping the file in as input? I don't understand how the `for line in file:` line would work in that instance

Comment: Predefine `n`, and then do something like `for i in range(n): ... x, y, z = [int(item) for item in input().split()]`. Everything else should be more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `pandas` to read a file:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("items.txt", delimiter=" ", header=None, names=["a", "b", "c"])
items = [threeItems(**item) for item in df.to_dict("records")]

print(f"{items[1].a=}")
for item in items:
    print(f"{item.a=}, {item.b=}, {item.c=}")
```

outputs:

```
items[1].a=4
item.a=0, item.b=3, item.c=2
item.a=4, item.b=5, item.c=8
```